# Identify which of the following sets are compact and which are not.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Identify which of the following sets are compact and which are not. If $E$ is not compact, find the smallest compact set $H$ (if there is one) such that $E \subset H$.

**a)** $E = \{ \frac{1}{k} : k \in N \} \cup \{0\}$.

attempt: compact: Since the set $\{ \frac{1}{k} : k \in \mathbb N \}$ contains zero and zero is a limit point, and it is contained in $E$, then $E$ is closed it is bounded by $1$.

**b)** $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : a^2 \leq x^2 + y^2 \leq b \}$ for real numbers $0 < a < b$.

attempt: compact, since suppose $ x^2 + y^2 = a^2 $  and $ x^2 + y^2 = b^2 $ then $a,b$ are limit points on $E$, so  $E$ is closed and bounded by $b$.

**c)** $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y = \sin(1/x) \}$ for some $x \in (0, 1]$

attempt: $E$ is bounded since $|\sin(1/x)| \leq 1$ for all $x \in (0, 1]$,
but I am not sure if it's closed.

**d)** $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : |xy| \leq 1 \}$

attempt:

Can someone please check if part $a), b)$ are correct with the explanations. And can someone please help me with part $c)$ and $d)$?
I would really appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: I've edited the expression $E = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : y = \sin(1/x) \}$ and other like it so that the "equals" sign and the curly braces are inside the MathJax tags.  That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: In part a), it doesn't make sense to say that your set "approaches zero when $k \to \infty$." You would say that 0 is a limit point of that set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're OK in $(a)$ and $(b)$.

In part $(c)$, the points $\left(\frac2\pi, 1\right), \left(\frac2{5\pi}, 1\right), \left(\frac2{9\pi}, 1\right), \ldots$ are members of the set but they converge to $(0,1)$, which is not a member.  Therefore the set is not closed.  And likewise if $-1\le y\le 1$ then every term of the sequence $(1/\arcsin (y+2\pi n), y)$ belongs to the set, and the sequence converges to $(0,y)$, which does not belong.

In part $(d)$, the whole $x$-axis is a subset, so the set is not bounded.  (And likewise the $y$-axis.)